# Outlook redemption to access PST from multiple machine

Tags: outlook-redemption

i wanted to create project in C#.net,where i can access same PST file from Multiple Machine ..

Is that possible using Redemption Dll ?

Please suggest we tried using 'RDOSession.LogonPstStore' but its not working in multiple machine for same PST.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, neither OOM, Extended MAPI, or Redemption will allow to access the same PST from multiple machines. The PST provider can only share a PST file between processes running in the same security context on the same machine.

Comment: Dmitry, thanks for Information, just having one question for generating RTF/Text from Message for large size PST Files, how can we Improve process speed ?

Comment: What is the question? How to open messages faster? Or are you having problems with SaveAs?

Comment: Yes both opening Message & save as process takes more time to process 5GB PST, so question is for improving that process, how can we have speed up with extraction process ?

Comment: Please create a new thread and post the relevant snippets of your existing code.